# WPF Trigger Скрыть вложенные элементы при наведении курсора

Tags: wpf, триггер

В Grid размещена кнопка, при наведении на Grid кнопка должна исчезать

Вот триггер в кнопке

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"
                Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

Проблема в том, что **1.** свойство кнопки меняется тогда, когда курсор находится над каком либо элементом в Grid, то есть на пустом месте не реагирует, и **2.** например свойство fontSize для кнопки меняется, а Visibility  - нет
В чем ошибка? что исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По поводу реакции над пустым местом: судя по всему, у вас у `Grid`'а нет фона. Поставьте ему какой-нибудь `Background`. Если никакой не нужен, поставьте `Transparent`.

По поводу `Visibility`: может быть у вас какое-то `Visibility` прописано прямо в кнопке? Непосредственно присвоенное значение перекрывает значения, заданные в стиле.

Comment: Действительно, спасибо за оперативный ответ)

Comment: @Ni55aN: Пожалуйста!